# fonts in chromium browser changed after installing calibre

Tags: fonts, chrome

I have installed `calibre`

```
apt-get install calibre
```

and since then the fonts in my chromium browser have changed.

Is there a way to revert the fonts back ?

Comment: I am not really convinced of calibre merits. I installed it on the past and it is awful.

Comment: @Rui F Ribeiro - how else would you convert epub to pdf ?

Comment: I used it on a Mac...other ways. It was just that was slow and unstable.